# carry a php array to javascript and Plot witjh jqplot

Tags: php, arrays, jqplot

I'm work with jqplot and I've plot a data that comes from array php but when I try to plot from javascript not works

This is the code php:

```php
$array= array();
$array[] = 34.890;
$array[] = 25.090;
```

Now the code imbibe:

```js
 <script>
 $(function() {

    var array = new Array();

    <?php
        for( $i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
           echo "\narray[$i] = '$array[$i]';"; 
         }
   ?>
   graficar(  array  );
 });
 </script>
```

The function graficar is:

```js
function graficar( array )
{

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('lienzo',
        [
            array
        ],
        {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                // Show point labels to the right ('e'ast) of each bar.
                // edgeTolerance of -15 allows labels flow outside the grid
                // up to 15 pixels.  If they flow out more than that, they
                // will be hidden.
                pointLabels: {show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15},
                // Rotate the bar shadow as if bar is lit from top right.
                shadowAngle: 135,
                // Here's where we tell the chart it is oriented horizontally.
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                    barWidth:18
                }
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        }
   );

 }
```

The mistake that I get is:

```js
TypeError: this[r]._ticks[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

 ...{href:function(a){return a.getAttribute("href")},type:function(a){return a.getAt...
```

The chart shows:

[image]

How to fix me trouble?

Tanks.

Comment: Try with json_encode in php and in js parseJson(Jquery) :-)

Comment: also, smarty allows you to pass php arrays to html pages, and then you can call those arrays with javascript

Comment: As KA_lin says use json_encode in php to make your array understandable by javascript. However, no need to use parseJson in Javascript, Jqplot can handle it

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in your "array", as in my code, when

```
array = ["0","0","0","0"]
```

or

```
array = ["w","r","o","n","g"]
```

the error occured, then I should use the parseInt method to parse string element to integer in the first.If

```
array = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

there's no need to parse the string element to intger in the array, jqplot will do it for you, but if the array just like the first two, here errors come.